# Snowflake Slow Insert with less amount of data (Number of rows)

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a stored procedure (Javascript language) having MERGE command to INSERT/UPDATE and DELETE data w.r.t condition. Code is working fine when we are inserting large amount of data (number of rows), but there are some cases where we need to insert 1 row at a time, at that time inserting data into table is very very slow. On Average it is taking 2 to 3 sec or more sometime for just 1 row.

- What could be reasons of slowness even with LARGE VWH usage?
- Do MERGE operations slower than INSERT operation?
- Any other reason?

Any help would be Appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Snowflake normally has some overhead when starting a process so what you are seeing is almost certainly expected behaviour. Snowflake is (or at least has been) designed to process large volumes of data and so is tuned to do this efficiently; it is it not designed to process single transactions in sub-second times like a transactional system is designed to do

Comment: Thanks for the explaining this @NickW- appreciate it